# Docker swarm in RPi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, docker

I am trying to create a swarm cluster of Raspberry Pi(s). I have installed docker and docker machine in the Raspberry Pi. I intend to make one of the Raspberry Pis to be the Manager node.

When I am executing the command:

```
 docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.148
```

It is giving me an error:

```
docker: 'swarm' is not a docker command.
```

Am I missing any basic configuration or I haven't installed any necessary package?

I have followed all the instructions from:
[Docker Documents](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed docker did you just install the one from the Repos (on raspbian)? The output of `docker version` would be helpful.

I seem to remember there is old (1.3 or thereabouts) version of docker in the Repos for raspbian which predates swarm.

If you setup docker via the [foundations guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/) it adds newer repos to apt in order to get the latest versions.

You'd then install docker as `docker-engine` to get a version with swarm.

Comment: Thanks.. But after I have executed: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`, it is showing me: `W: Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/raspbian-jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none`

Comment: You might need to `sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine` to remove your old version then `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates apt-transport-https` before running that script. Those are the steps from the debian instructions https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/#uninstall-old-versions on the Docker website.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually the concern was regarding the "date" in my RPi.. But surely thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

On a `Raspberry Pi 3 model B` running `Raspbian Jessie` if you follow these steps to install Docker swarm it will work!

```
# update and reboot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo shutdown –r now

# Install Docker
$ curl –sSL https://get.docker.com | sh

# Add pi user to docker group
$ sudo usermod –aG docker pi

# restart to apply usermod changes
$ sudo shutdown –r now

# As pi user, check that Docker is working with the
$ Docker info

# Create swarm 
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.148
```

My thought is that maybe you have not added your `pi` user to the docker group.